# How to print csv report in browser odoo?

Tags: csv, odoo, odoo-10

I am trying to print some fields of  **account.invoice** and **account.invoice.line**

Firstly I added the button for printing csv formatted report.

this is i trying in code

```py
def print_csv(self):      
    lines = []
    lines.append((['Product Name','Price Unit','Quantity']))
    for rec in self.invoice_line_ids:  
      lines.append(([rec.product_id.name,rec.price_unit,rec.quantity]))        
    with open('invoice_details.csv', 'w') as fp:
        a = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',')            
        data_lines = lines
        a.writerows(data_lines)
```

the csv file file is downloaded in not browser,it is downloaded in the default location.

How to redirect to the file to download in web browser??

I know this can implemented using controllers in odoo.
is there any good example of controller to print csv report??

Comment: If you go to the tree view and select some records and then `Actions > Export` you can export the fields you want in CSV format

Comment: If it is not what you want take a look to the modules `report_xls` and `report_xlsx`. They will give you some idea

Comment: @ChesuCR:thanks for the valuable information